# A problem of (Convex?) Optimization about compressive sensing

Tags: matrices, derivatives, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, compression

In fact, I'm not sure if the following question is convex.

I am processing an optimization problem about compressive sensing:

$$\arg\min_{A,x} \quad \lVert Ax-y \rVert _{2}^{2}+\lambda _1\lVert A^{\top}Ax-x \rVert _{2}^{2}+\lambda _2\lVert x \rVert _1$$

where $A$ should be an $m\times n$ $(m\ll n)$ matrix, $x$ should be an $n$-d vector, and $y$, $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ are given. Especially, $A$ is **variable** intead of constant matrix.

Does we can solve this problem by using an iterative method like ISTA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use a proximal gradient method such as ISTA. Recall that the general framework is $$\min_\mathbf{x} f(\mathbf{x}) + g(\mathbf{x})$$
where $f(\mathbf{x})$ is differentiable and $g(\mathbf{x})$ is convex. Then actually it's possible to solve this in two ways:

1. Define:

   - $f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{2}\|A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^2_2+\frac{\lambda_1}{2}\|A^TA\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}\|^2_2$
   - $g(\mathbf{x})= \lambda_2\|\mathbf{x}\|_1$
2. Define:

   - $f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{2}\|A\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^2_2$
   - $g(\mathbf{x})= \frac{\lambda_1}{2}\|A^TA\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}\|^2_2+\lambda_2\|\mathbf{x}\|_1$

Notice that $\|A^TA\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}\|^2_2=\|(A^TA-I)\mathbf{x}\|^2_2$. This will make it easier to get the derivative. Also, if you take the second approach, then deriving a proximal operator for $g(\cdot)$ is not difficult, since [under certain conditions](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2013/file/98dce83da57b0395e163467c9dae521b-Paper.pdf), which apply in this case, $\text{prox}_{g_1+g_2}=\text{prox}_{g_1}\circ\text{prox}_{g_2}$. The proximal operator of the $l_1$ norm is the well known soft thresholding operator, and getting an explicit prox formula for the second term in $g(\cdot)$ is also not complicated. Then all you have to do is compose them.

Lastly, I would recommend to use an **accelerated** prox-grad method such as [FISTA](https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Ebecka/FISTA.pdf) to get much better performance than ISTA.

Comment: I doubt that you can decompose the prox map in the case presented here.

Comment: @gerw a sufficient condition is that $\forall x\in\text{dom}\,g_1:\;\partial g_1(x)\subseteq \partial g_1(\text{prox}_{g_2}(x))$. I think it might apply by defining $g_1$ as the squared $l_2$ norm and $g_2$ as the $l_1$ norm. If this indeed holds then I assume the algorithm will perform faster than in the first setting. But in any case, the first setting is good and easy to implement, and using an accelerated scheme it will have good convergence properties

Comment: I think there is a little gap between this answer and my original problem. Does ISTA could solve this problem where $A$ is variable instead of a constant matrix? Could I update $A$ and $\mathbf{x}$ simultaneously at the first step of each iteration, and then perform a proximal mapping on $\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: If $A$ is a variable then you have a completely different problem. Prominently, this is no longer a convex problem. You could potentially introduce a new variable $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{z}$, however the second term couples $A\mathbf{z},\mathbf{x}$ together. Your problem will take the form $\min_{A,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z}}f(\mathbf{z})+g(A\mathbf{z},\mathbf{x})+h(\mathbf{x})$, with the constraint $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{z}$. This is quite a lot to handle. Are you sure $A$ is a variable?

Comment: Yes... I don't know how to process. Does there exists an iterative method to solve it?

Comment: @BinChen No. This is a hard, non-convex problem. Do you know what you're trying to model? Why do you even want to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm wondering if I can reconstruct an image from some measurements without knowing the sampling matrix, the prerequisite is that I could use SVD or PCA to generate a relative good sampling matrix from the image to be compressed. So when I receive the measurement $\mathbf{y}$, I can get my $\mathbf{x}$ by solving the problem that I proposed. I thought it would work, and I wanted to perform some experiments. But the above optimization problem is non-convex and hard as you said. Maybe I could try some other directions. :)

Comment: @BinChen what you're asking sounds almost impossible, I have to say. Normally when we have a compressed signal, we are aware of the original compressing transformation $A$, and the mathematical problem is inversing that compression. If you don't know the transformation, I really find it difficult to think of a way to infer it + the original signal. Maybe there's some literature in the field that will help you. Once you have an optimization problem in place, I will be able to help with the algorithmic framework

Comment: I get it. Thank you very much~